# Connect to MSSQL from PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to connect to **MS SQL** DB from **PySpark** using **spark.read.jdbc**.

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark import SparkContext;
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext('xx')
spark = SparkSession(sc)

    spark.read.jdbc('DESKTOP-XXXX\SQLEXPRESS',
"""(select COL1, COL2 from tbl1 WHERE COL1 = 2) """,
properties={'user': sa, 'password': 12345, 'driver': xxxx})
```

I do not know `sc = SparkContext('xx')` and `'driver': xxxx` which parameters should I pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `serveraddress` with your address of database:

```
sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
spark.read \
     .format('jdbc') \
     .option('url', 'jdbc:sqlserver://serveraddress:1433') \
     .option('user', 'sa') \
     .option('password', '12345') \
     .option('dbtable', '(select COL1, COL2 from tbl1 WHERE COL1 = 2)')
```

Comment: Code works, then I do load df:

  File "..\spark\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 172, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "..\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1256, in __call__
  File "..\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco return f(*a, **kw)
  File "..\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)

Comment: That's because you don't have the JDBC driver for SQL server in your spark/jars folder. See my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65060192/load-dataframe-from-pyspark/65060237#65060237

Comment: I saw it. when I downloaded, in download rar file are many files, I should put in spark/jars folder only 3 .jar files?

Comment: `When you download the driver, there are multiple JAR files. The name of the JAR file indicates the version of Java that it supports.`

Comment: Choose the appropriate jar file according to the java version in your system, and **only** put that into your spark/jars folder

Comment: I have java version "1.8.0_271". name of files are (jre8.jar, jre11.jar, jre14.jar). I need second one?

Comment: use jre8.jar - 1.8.0 corresponds to java 8