# Load dataframe from PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to connect to **MS SQL** DB from **PySpark** using **spark.read.jdbc**

```
import os
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark import SparkContext;
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)

df = spark.read \
     .format('jdbc') \
     .option('url', 'jdbc:sqlserver://local:1433') \
     .option('user', 'sa') \
     .option('password', '12345') \
     .option('dbtable', '(select COL1, COL2 from tbl1 WHERE COL1 = 2)')
```

then I do df.load() and returns an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 172, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1256, in __call__
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\spark\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o42.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:105)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:32)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download the JDBC driver and put it into your spark/jars folder.

For SQL SERVER JDBC driver, you can download it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15